# Make constructor available across js files

Tags: javascript, constructor, requirejs

I am calling the following constructor function:

```
  deck.tracker = new ActivityTracker();
```

All runs through if I define this in the same file/context:

```
   function ActivityTracker() {}
```

But as soon as I move:

```
    function ActivityTracker() {}
```

to a separate file and include it before the other file is called, the scope breaks. How can I fix this without changing this line:

```
     deck.tracker = new ActivityTracker();
```

Note: the importing needs to be conditional:  if (window.location.href.indexOf("http://0.0.0.0") == 0 || window.location.href.indexOf('http://local') == 0) { then import }.

so using import/export which can only be top-level does not work.

Comment: You aren't wrapping your `ActivityTracker` definition within an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately_invoked_function_expression) are you?

Comment: How are you _"including"_ these JS files? Is this in a browser or Node app?

Comment: In a browser, including them with  <script src="newTracker.js"></script> and r(['scripts/auditor.build'], function() { ....

Comment: What is `r()`? You're going to have to share more of `newTracker.js` if you want any help with this

Comment: It's syntax from require.js, a module loader

Answer (score 0):

You just need to import it first:

In your separate file:

```
function ActivityTracker() {}
export ActivityTracker;
```

In your main file:

```
import { ActivityTracker } from "./separateFile";
deck.tracker = new ActivityTracker();
```

Comment: When I add this, I get: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export (and import)

Comment: Or maybe I don't have support for ES6? how can I find out, and are there alternatives to import/export?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use [javascript es6 modules](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-use-es6-modules-and-why-theyre-important-a9b20b480773) and just import the function from another file.

In the main file:

```
import { ActivityTracker } from 'somefileurl'

deck.tracker = new ActivityTracker();
```

Then in the file containing `ActivityTracker` function:

```
function ActivityTracker() {}

export ActivityTracker
```